# Find the limit of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]
I've been trying to solve a bunch of these limits by turning to polar coordinates, though I could only deal with the ones that have x and y approaching zero. In this particular case nothing points to this limit being independent of r, and trigonometric functions can't be reduced(easily). I would really appreciate it if you could break down the steps right after applying equivalence and turning to polar coordinates.

Comment: Have you tried substituting $(x,y)=(2+u,2+v)$, then using polar coordinates in $(u,v)$?  i.e. $(u,v)=r(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the limit as
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}
\frac{(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4) + \tan(x^2-y^2)}
{\sin[(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4)] -(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)xy+\tan^{-1}[(x^2-y^2)\frac{xy}{x+y}] }
$$
Now note that as $\xi \to 0$, if $A$ is nonzero but finite, then
$$
\sin(\xi A) \to \xi A + O(\xi^2) \\
\tan(\xi A) \to \xi A + O(\xi^2) \\
\tan^{-1}(\xi A) \to \xi A + O(\xi^2)
$$
and taking $\xi = x^2-y^2$ this reduces the limit to
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}
\frac{(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4) + (x^2-y^2)}
{(x^2-y^2)(x^4+x^2y^2+y^4) -(x^2-y^2)(x^2+y^2)xy+(x^2-y^2)\frac{xy}{x+y} }\\
= \lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)}\frac{x^4+x^2y^2+y^4 +1}
{x^4+x^2y^2+y^4 -(x^2+y^2)xy+\frac{xy}{x+y} }\\
= \frac{2^4+2^22^2+2^4 +1}
{2^4+2^22^2+2^4 -(2^2+2^2)2\cdot 2+\frac{2\cdot 2}{2+2} }= \frac{49}{17}
$$

Answer (score 0):

One thing to notice is that the full limit doesn't exist. Meaning, you can't let $(x,y) \to (2,2)$ unrestrictedly. You have to stay off the line $y=x.$ Otherwise we run into the undefined $0/0.$

A key idea is to factor out the troublesome $(x-y)$ wherever we can. For example we can write $x^6 - y^6 = (x-y)a(x,y),$ where hopefully you recall the formula for $a(x,y).$ Here's a more complicated example:

$$\tag 1\sin (x^6 - y^6) = \sin [(x-y)a(x,y)] = (x-y)\cdot\frac{\sin [(x-y)a(x,y)]}{(x-y)a(x,y)}\cdot a(x,y).$$

Notice that as $(x,y) \to (2,2),$ the second and third factors in $(1)$ have limits of $1$ and $a(2,2)$ respectively.

Do this upstairs and downstairs, cancel all the $(x-y)$'s, and you'll have an understandable limit.

Comment: No, this particular limit does exist, because approaching $2,2)$ from any direction along any curve gives the same limit value.

Comment: @MarkFischler  No, the function is not defined on the line $y=x,$ so approaching $(2,2)$ along this line makes no sense.

Comment: The limit still exists since $lim_{y\to x}f(x,y)$ does exist for each value of $x$.

Comment: @MarkFischlerI don't know how to make it any clearer: The function is not defined on the line $y=x,$ so letting $(x,y) \to (2,2)$ along this line makes no sense.